# Ajax spinner not hiding when ajax request completes or fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal that I am showing when user clicks on a submit button

```
<div class="modal fade" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" th:fragment="signupSuccessMessageModalFragment">   
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 48px">
            <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript code when user clicks on the button

```
$('#registerUser').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var pleaseWait = $('#pleaseWaitDialog');
var developerData = {};
developerData["userName"] = $("#userName").val().trim();
developerData["email"] = $("#email").val().trim();
pleaseWait.modal('show');
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    contentType : "application/json",
    url : '/signup',
    data : JSON.stringify(developerData),
    dataType : 'json'
}).done(function(result) {
    window.location.replace("/signup_success?email="+email); 
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        // Move to a new location or you can do something else
        window.location.href = "https://www.google.co.in";
    }, 5000);
}).fail(function(result) {
    pleaseWait.modal('hide');
    var errors = $.parseJSON(result.responseJSON.message);
    $.each(errors, function(key, value) {
            var divid = "#" + value.field + "Error";
            $("#"+value.field+"Error").show().append(value.defaultMessage+"<br/>");
    });
}).always(function() {
    pleaseWait.modal('hide');
})
});
```

Before start of the request bootstrap modal(#pleaseWaitDialog) launches and ajax spinner shows up. But the modal is not closing when request fails[pleaseWait.modal('hide');//Not working]. What am i missing here ? Thanks

update - Here is my fiddle containing complete code, its not working since I am new to jsfiddle and my code is making server side validation request (working on it) [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sphoenix/89shpb2n/)

My requirements
1. User clicks on Create Account button -> spinner start showing up
2. In case of fail spinner should hide 
3. In case of success page is getting redirected to signup success page hence spinner automatically hides

Comment: do you have a fiddle so we can look at this? are you sure it's actually failed?

Comment: Yes its failed since I am able to see console.log message which i used for confirmation purpose. I don't have a fiddle as of now , working on it and will post it soon

Comment: posted the fiddle

Comment: I am having a easy method to display loader while data is getting processed .put your gif loader image inside a div and then show that div on button click and then hide that div inside the ajax success function.Hope this helps.
OR you can try using modal('hide') inside your done function.

Comment: Your fiddle has an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: `});
}).always(function() ` The is one `});` to many.